# Opacity function for Plot with multiple curves

Tags: plotting

I have a list of `functions` that I want to plot on the same figure. I want each line to have an opacity function that is defined by the list `weights`. In addition I want each colour of the line to be chosen in order from a colour scheme. My attempt:

```
parameters = Range[1, 5];
nParam = Length[parameters];
functions = # x & /@ parameters;
weights = Cos[# x]^2 & /@ parameters;
colorFunctions = Table[Opacity[weights[[n]], ColorData["Rainbow"][(n - 1)/(nParam - 1)]], {n, 1, nParam}]
Plot[functions, {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> colorFunctions]
```

How do I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parameters = Range[5];
functions = # x & /@ parameters;
nParam = Length[parameters];
colors = ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, nParam - 1}}] /@ (parameters - 1);
weights = Sin[# x] & /@ parameters;

plots= MapThread[Plot[#, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Opacity[##2]]] &,
   {functions, weights, colors}];

Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[plotF]
plotF[functions_, range_, weights_, cf_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{colors = ColorData[{cf, {0, Length[functions] - 1}}] /@ 
     Range[0, Length[functions] - 1], arg = range[[1]]}, 
  Show[MapThread[Plot[#, range, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> Function[Evaluate@arg, Opacity[##2]]] &, 
   {functions, weights, colors}], opts, PlotRange -> All]]
```

**Examples:**

```
plotF[{x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], 
  Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], Sin[5 x]}, "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

```
plotF[{Sin[y], Cos[y], y Sin[y]}, {y, 0, 10}, {Sin[y], Sin[2 y], 
  Sin[3 y]}, "DeepSeaColors", Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: If possible, could you suggest how to turn this into a function that takes `functions` and `weights` as parameters, as well as a plot range (with variable) such as `{x, 0, 2 Pi}` and produces the same result. BUT such that we can pass different variables. i.e. `functions = {Cos[y], Sin[y]}` and `{y, 0, 10}` etc.

Comment: @Tom, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I have slightly modified your answer, and added `ColorFunctionScaling->False` so that it works properly. Otherwise it rescales the x-range of the colour function to be in (0,1)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution. Not very elegant though.

```
parameters = Range[1, 5];
nParam = Length[parameters];
functions = # x & /@ parameters;
weights = Cos[# x]^2 & /@ parameters;
colorFunction[m_] := With[{n = m}, Function[x , Opacity[Sin[x n], ColorData["Rainbow"][(n - 1)/(nParam - 1)]]]];
plot[n_] := Plot[functions[[n]], {x, 0, Pi}, ColorFunction -> colorFunction[n]]
plots = Table[plot[n], {n, 1, nParam}];
Show[plots, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]